# How to serialize a user regarding authentication?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm have an authenticated section on my app, but the authentication is done via oauth to a 3rd party service. I get the 200 callback from the service, now I create/find my user and set him as logged in.

So my provider is:

```
providers:
    users:
        entity: { class: MainBundle:User, property: id }
```

My user implements the security's UserInterface, although I don't have the username, password, etc properties on my user entity. I assume the id is then the only identifier I can use then.

My token is set as follows:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'secured_area', $user->getRoles());
$this->securityContext->setToken($token);
```

I wish to do this without using JMS bundle for now; my serialization looks like this:

```
/**
 * Serialize
 * @return string|void
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        'id' => $this->getId(),
        'display_name' => $this->getDisplayName(),
        'email' => $this->getEmail(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Unserialize
 * @return mixed|void
 */
public function unserialize($data)
{
    $data = unserialize($data);
    $this->setId($data['id']);
    $this->setDisplayName($data['display_name']);
    $this->setEmail($data['email']);
    return $this;
}
```

Using the above I get an infinite loop redirect.

At first I only serialized the id, but then all the other properties of the user isn't available.

Then I tried serializing the whole object ($this), but that gives me a xdebug nesting level error of 1000.

I'm a bit lost of how to make this authentication work with serialization

Comment: In Symfony2, `JMSSerializerBundle` is usually used to serialize Entities. Have you looked into that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

security.yml

```
providers:
    users:
        entity: { class: MainBundle:User, property: id }
```

login logic

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'secured_area', $user->getRoles());
$this->securityContext->setToken($token);
```

I took out the serialization out of the user entity, also not implementing equatable interface. Also still do not have the interface properties, although this is needed:

```
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->getId();
}
```