# How to redirect unauthorized requests in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

Note: I [manually authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520265/how-to-serialize-a-user-regarding-authentication#answer-14563732) the user.

My security config is as follows:

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: login_check
            login_path: about
        remember_me:
            key: %secret%
            lifetime: 31536000
            path: /
            domain: ~
        logout: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/(login|about), roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

My idea is that if the user is not authorized, he is redirected to the about page. Then from there he clicks on the login link, and I manually authenticate his credentials.

At the moment it's half-working. The problem is the about page:

1) there's no styling although the assets seems to load correctly,

2) it seems to redirect a lot to itself (?) It seems it should trigger an infinite loop, but then stops? Theory: why does it reload the about page for every asset?

3) would my remember me even work?

Current status:
[image]

EDIT:
It's the assetic. Taking it out of assetic makes it work. But I would still like to use assetic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just re-direct to the login page when the user is not authorised?

Comment: The login page actually goes to oauth authentication to a webservice (as I said I do manual auth). I can do that, but then there'll be 3 unauth allowed pages, so it just is another step. The problem will still persist. I still need that one landing page for new visitors. tl;dr the `/` route requires auth, so on landing on the domain you need to go to `/about`.